# Display Error from Extended Http Service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an extended Http service, following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/mrgoos/45ab013c2c044691b82d250a7df71e4c), that is essentially serving as a request error handler. When an error from a request returns a 401 status, I am having it redirect the user to a 'denied' page. At the moment, I am able to catch the errors and redirect them without issues and I can also see the status response output to the console. However, I want to be able to subscribe/display, through my component, the body of the error that is being returned from the service call.

I was hoping that someone might be able to show me how to utilize this service and display the error in my denied component.

Here is what my extended class looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Request, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable
export class ErrorHttpService extends Http {

  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private router:Router){
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options)
      .catch((error: Response) => {
        if ((error.status === 401)) {
          this.router.navigate(['denied'])
        }
       return Observable.throw(error); //how can I get this into 'denied'
    });
  }

}
```

Here is my denied.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ErrorHttpService} from "../_services/error-http.service";

//component info removed

export class DeniedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ErrorHttpService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    //how to subscribe to error thrown in ErrorHttpService
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't know the size of these errors, but send the error as a param to your DeniedComponent  can do the job.

Comment: Yep, either use a service or query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I ended up taking a different approach and creating a service with a cached observable (error message) which allowed me to spread it amongst components without multiple requests. Will post an update soon.